# Beautiful Soup table.find_all = NoneType

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, html-table, nonetype, findall

As you can see my code is not terribly complicated but, for some reason whenever I try to use .find_all or some variation of find_all I get a NoneType error when using it without "soup". I know its not a 404 problem because I can print "table" just fine. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling beautiful soup as well as variations of importing beautiful soup or bs4. I've tried using requests instead of urllib2.

I've also tried using lxml but it doesn't work so well with the site I'm scrapping

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
url = urllib2.urlopen(
"http://www.adviserinfo.sec.gov/IAPD/content/viewform/adv/Sections/iapd_AdvScheduleASection.aspx?ORG_PK=100&FLNG_PK=0515B1FC0008018205B8D80005C8A651056C8CC0"
).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(url)
table = soup.find(
"table",id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMainContent_cphAdvFormContent_ScheduleAPHSection_ctl00_ownersGrid"
)

for row in table.find_all("tr"):
    cells = row.find_all('td')
    print cells


Error = for row in table.find_all("tr"):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

> > > 

Comment: You are using BeautifulSoup version **three**; `find_all` is the new name used in version 4, replacing `findAll`. You really, really want to upgrade to 4 however: `pip install beautifulsoup4` then `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: That works! thats so weird I was trying all the variations of find_all/findAll nothing was working but now it is (not complaining lol) cant seem to import from bs4 even though my pip tells me its up to date and installed

Comment: re-installed bs4 working fine now